# How can I revert to a recently saved game in borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

Yesterday I finished the normal game by killing Jack.

Today I started borderlands 2 and selected my character. I was given three choices: "Normal," "True Vault Hunter" and "Cancel."

I selected "Normal," assuming I'd resume my game where I left off yesterday. Instead, I was dumped into a second playthrough. Our friend clap trap was digging around and guided me to his home. NOTE: I did not inadvertently select "True Vault Hunter." I selected "Normal" and was PLACED into a True Vault Hunter game.

I quit the game as soon as I was able, and was forced to save it. Resuming that "Normal" game placed me into the "True Vault Hunter" game. (They are one and the same.)

My local save data is the same data steam has on its cloud.

Is there any way I can revert my saved game back to the point where it was previously?

I'm playing a Steam copy of Borderlands 2 for PC if that matters.

Comment: You did everything correctly, from your description. Probably you just hit TVHM by accident. As per the duplicate, just go out to the menu, and choose Normal again, and you'll be back where you were.

Comment: I did that. With no success. Fortunately had made my way through the game with a friend. He started his game up and suggested joining it. I did, and BAM! All my progress was back.

Comment: Did not hit "True Vault Hunter" by accident. Selected "Normal" but the game started in "True Vault Hunter" mode.

Comment: Not a duplicate question, guys. Please re-read the post.

Comment: Yes, it is. This question is asking how to get back into the playthrough you already completed, after having started another. The duplicate asks how to get back into the playthrough you already completed, after having started another. Follow the steps on the Duplicate question, and if that doesn't work, then you're experiencing a bug, and need to contact Gearbox.

Comment: No, it absolutely is not a duplication question. I don't see what's so hard to understand about this. I selected "normal" and was put into a "true vault hunter" game. I cannot go back to the character screen and select "normal" again and expect something completely different. Further, my question asked if there was a way to revert to a saved game.